# Produce extra records using given frequency

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Here is a sample of the representative data:

| Duration | Frequency | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| M | 1 | Date1 |
| M | 1 | Date2 |
| Q | 3 | Date3 |
| H | 6 | Date4 |
| A | 12 | Date5 |

I want to run a SQL query on this data & replicate data as per the given frequency:

| Duration | Date |
| --- | --- |
| M | Date1 |
| M | Date2 |
| Q | Date3 |
| Q | Date3 |
| Q | Date3 |
| H | Date4 |
| H | Date4 |
| H | Date4 |
| H | Date4 |
| H | Date4 |
| H | Date4 |
| A | Date5 |
| A | Date5 |
| A | Date5 |
| A | Date5 |
| A | Date5 |
| A | Date5 |
| A | Date5 |
| A | Date5 |
| A | Date5 |
| A | Date5 |
| A | Date5 |
| A | Date5 |

I haven't gotten very far unfortunately. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Use a Tally, and then JOIN to that on the frequency being greater than or equal to the tally.

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in the comment, use a tally to create your rows, and then `JOIN` to it:

```sql
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (SELECT MAX(Frequency) FROM dbo.YourTable)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2) --100 rows, add more cross joins for more rows
SELECT YT.Duration,
       YT.[Date]
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN Tally T ON YT.Frequency > T.I;
```